# Rename Library Name using SDK C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I change a library name using C# SDK on SharePoint online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used below code to rename sp list or library

```
 using System; 
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.Linq; using System.Text;
 using Microsoft.SharePoint; 
 namespace TestApp 
{ 
    class Program 
   {  
        public static SPWeb Web; 
        public const string LIST_NAME = "List Name"; 
       static void Main(string[] args) 
      { 
           SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server:port/");
           Web = site.RootWeb; SPList list =     Web.Lists[LIST_NAME];
           Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            list.Fields["Title"].Title = "NewTitle"; 
            list.Fields["Title"].Description = "Test descr";
          list.Fields["Title"].Update();
          Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 
       } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I want to change the name of the library that appears in URL too not just the title, could you help, please

Comment: You can't change name of url. To change name in URL you have to create new sp list or sp library

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace TokenAuthentication
{
    class Program
    {
       static string Passwords = "Password";
        static string UserName = "UserName";
        static string SiteURL = "Site URL";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (ClientContext clientCont = new ClientContext(SiteURL))
            {
                SecureString passWord2 = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in Passwords.ToCharArray()) passWord2.AppendChar(c);
                clientCont.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, passWord2);

                Web oWeb= clientCont.Web;
                 List oList = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List Name");
                oList.Title = "Updated List Name";
                oList.Description = "List description";
                oList.Update();
                clientCont.ExecuteQuery();       

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change the name of the library that appears in URL too not just the title, could you help, please!